# checkboxes for table records

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.2

I want to let user to publish or unpublish some articles at once. So, in articles list view, I want to put a checkbox beside each row (article) and send these checkboxes to controller.

I tried to use `$this->Form->input('status')` after each row in my loop, but it created same checkbox for each article. (inputs name and id are the same)

How to create an array of checkboxes or something like this? And how to check them in controller?

**Note:** Each article has a `status` field, which is a `tinyint` 1 character field. (so Cake can understand it's a checkbox)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to specify an 'index' for each input.

In stead of this:

```
$this->Form->input('Article.status');
```

Use this:

```
$this->Form->input('Article.0.id');
$this->Form->input('Article.0.status');
$this->Form->input('Article.1.id');
$this->Form->input('Article.1.status');
// .... 
$this->Form->input('Article.xxx.id');
$this->Form->input('Article.xxx.status');
```

It's the 'index' is just a counter to make sure that 'unique' inputs are generated. However, it *is* important that each row contains an input for the `id` of that row; CakePHP will need that to determin *which* record it should update the status for.

### Further reading

Documentation on the naming of fields/inputs can be found here:

[FormHelper field naming conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#field-naming-conventions)

[CakePHP - Create a form which edits multiple rows of the same model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391452/cakephp-create-a-form-which-edits-multiple-rows-of-the-same-model)