# Multiple record insert

Tags: cakephp

My table structure is something like below :

```
==============================
  Id | Name | Image|
==============================
```

Now i want to multiple image with name.How can i do this.

```
if($this->request->is('post'))
        {
            if($this->Breakdown->saveAll($this->request->data['Breakdown']))
            {
            //Image insertion Successfully
            $image=$this->request->data['Breakdown'][0]['image1']['name'];
            if(!empty($this->request->data['Breakdown'][0]['image1']['name'])) 
                {
                    $image_path = $this->Image->upload_image_and_thumbnail($image,$this->data['Breakdown'][0]['image1'],600,450,180,120, "Breakdown");
                    //echo "This".$image_path;
                    if(isset($image_path)) 
                    {
                        $this->Breakdown->saveField('image',$image_path);
                        $uploaded = true;
                    }
                }
               $this->Session->setFlash('Quantity Breakdown has been added Successfully.', 'default', array('class' => 'oMsg1 oMsgError1'));
               $this->redirect('qty_breakdown');
            }
            else
            {
                 $this->set('errors', $this->Breakdown->invalidFields());   
            }
```

Is there any alternate way to use loop for inserting and uploading multiple image?

Comment: apply `foreach` for `$this->request->data['Breakdown']`, extract individual element and use `save` instead of `saveAll`.

Comment: And what should be the name of input box and file in view.Now my view contain [Breakdown][name] for name field and [Breakdown][0][image1] for image.

Comment: add the input field name with array like `name = "image[]"` in the view. it will post image name as an array. Check if this will work

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you're asking but if you meant, to iterate over each 'Breakdown' entity, this is how I would do it:

```
foreach($this->request->data['Breakdown'] as $breakdown){
    //Image insertion Successfully
    $image = $breakdown['image1']['name'];
    if(!empty($breakdown['image1']['name'])){
        $image_path = $this->Image->upload_image_and_thumbnail($image,$this->data['Breakdown'][0]['image1'],600,450,180,120, "Breakdown");
            //echo "This".$image_path;
            if(isset($image_path)){
                $this->Breakdown->saveField('image', $image_path);
                $uploaded = true;
            }
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash('Quantity Breakdown has been added Successfully.', 'default', array('class' => 'oMsg1 oMsgError1'));
        $this->redirect('qty_breakdown');
}
```

#### Update: 29/04/13

To be able to modify or add multiple records from within your view you need to configure your view a little differently:

```
// open the form
echo $this->Form->create('Breakdown');
// set the upper-bound limit of $i to whatever you like
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){
    echo $this->Form->input(sprintf("Breakdown.%d.image1", $i), array('type' => 'file'));
    // add other fields using similar syntax as above:
    // Example: "Breakdown.1.name"
}
// close the form
echo $this->Form->end();
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391452/cakephp-create-a-form-which-edits-multiple-rows-of-the-same-model)

Comment: And what should be the name of input box and file in view.Now my view contain [Breakdown][name] for name field and [Breakdown][0][image1] for image.

Comment: Your code is inserting last record only.Multiple record is not inserting..what can i do now??

Comment: Are you calling `$this->Breakdown->create()` between each call to `save()`? Alternatively, call `$this->Breakdown->saveMany()`. [Source](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-save-array-data-null-boolean-validate-true-array-fieldlist-array)